# React-Bootstrap - Card Component cannot be imported & Cannot install peer dependencies

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've been using react-bootstrap and so far most components are working except the Card component, and this is the error I've been getting:

Attempted import error: 'Card' is not exported from 'react-bootstrap'.

```js
import React, {Component} from "react"
import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";

export default class NewsCard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
                <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                    the card's content.
                    </Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
                </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            </div>
        )
        }
    }
```

When I install React-Bootstrap, I get this warning error also so the Card Component is missing from the dependency:

```
npm WARN react-bootstrap-card@0.2.1 requires a peer of react-bootstrap@^0.30.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

Has anyone else encountered this issue or can lead me to the right direction? thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the code you're using?

Comment: I've added my code snippet now

Comment: what version of react bootstrap is in your `package.json`?

Comment: @BillF I've got react-bootstrap 0.32.4

Comment: okay, i haven't used react-bootstrap but why is your Button just `import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap'` and not `import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'`? if you are not sure, try using `import {Card} from "react-bootstrap"`

Answer (score 4):

It's because Card only exists in the 1.0.0 beta version. You are using 0.32.4.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation for react-bootstrap looks like you also need to have `bootstrap` installed. I've got it working with the following import statement. Make sure youre importing `Card` and not `{ Card }` when using the `"react-bootstrap/Card"` import statement.

```
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Todo extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Card>
        <Card.Body>This is some text within a card body.</Card.Body>
      </Card>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todo />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: I've double checked those, and changed it to react-bootstrap/Card, but it's still showing an error on my end unfortunately

Comment: @tangnology try doing an `npm install` and re-trying, let me know how that goes

Comment: I've tried to delete all the node_modules and npm install all but the Card component is still missing from the react-bootstrap dependency. the warning error I'm getting is: 

npm WARN react-bootstrap-card@0.2.1 requires a peer of react-bootstrap@^0.30.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Tried to install peer dependencies but am not successful....

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this:

```js
import Card from "react-bootstrap/Card";
```

It's the little things!

```
npm install --save react-bootstrap bootstrap
```

Comment: it says it requires specific version  react-bootstrap@^0.30.7 so from this version up `npm install --save react-bootstrap@^0.30.7` is better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use the custom react elements made by react.

There is a module named **reactstrap**

install it as

```
npm install reactstrap
```

and use it by importing

```
import {Card, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, CardImg} from 'reactstrap';
```

The whole code becomes

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Card, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle, CardSubtitle, CardImg} from 'reactstrap';

import ss from '../../ss.png';

class HomePage extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Card >
                <CardImg style={{width:'18rem' }} variant="top" src={ss}/>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>Card Title</CardTitle>
                    <CardText>
                    Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.
                    </CardText>
                    <button >Go somewhere</button>
                </CardBody>
                </Card>

                <Card>
  <CardBody>This is some text within a card body.</CardBody>
</Card>

            </div>
        )
    }


}

export default HomePage;
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, with this error:

*export 'carddeck' (imported as 'carddeck') was not found in 'react-bootstrap'*

ante the problem was that whenever I do ***npm install react-bootstrap bootstrap@4.6.0*** it will install react-bootstrap version: 2.1.2 which is not fully compatible with bootstrap@4.6.0.

So the solution is **npm uninstall react-bootstrap bootstrap** if you already installed react-bootstrap and bootstrap before and force the installation of the 1.6.4 version by

**npm install react-bootstrap@1.6.4 bootstrap@4.6.0**

I also experienced problems with the accordions because of the same versions mix problems.